# How to enqueue script if widget is displayed on page?

Tags: theme-development, widgets, wp-enqueue-script

I created a widget that uses a jquery plugin, and I used is_active_widget to enqueue the script, it's working fine but it's also including the script even on pages that doesn't show this widget.
so is there a way to only enqueue the script if this widget is showing ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to call `wp_enqueue_script()` as part of your Widget output.

#### Edit

Quick-and-dirty, using the bare-bones [Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) class example:

```
<?php
class wpse48337_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        // widget actual processes
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget
    }

}
register_widget( 'wpse48337_Widget' );
?>
```

Add your `wp_enqueue_script()` call *inline*, within your Widget's **output** - i.e. within the `public function widget()`:

```
<?php    
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget

    // Enqueue a script needed for
    // the Widget's output
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-pluginname', $path, $deps );

    // Rest of widget output goes here...
    }
?>
```

Comment: Actually I'm doing that, and using is_active_widget() but it will enqueue the script on all pages if the widget is active even on one.

Comment: Using `is_active_widget()` is not the same as calling `wp_enqueue_script()` from *within your Widget **output***. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you for the update, but what do you mean by quick and dirty the example or this way for using wp_enqueue_script() ?
and one more off topic question please, I'm seeing a lot of these private and public before functions in widgets so what do they do ? and should we use them widgets specific for themes ? and thank you very much :)

Comment: By "*quick and dirty example*", I mean that I'm referencing the standard Widget class construct, as described in the linked Codex article. I'm **assuming** that you've written your custom Widget using the Widgets API. If not, you *should* be; but nonetheless, if you need more specific guidance, we'll need to see your Widget code.

Comment: This doesn't work. Not sure if it used to work since it was marked as an answer. But right now, the widget form is triggered after the wp_enqueue_scripts action

Comment: Working in 4.2.4

Comment: Does not work. wp_enqueue_script is not triggered at all when it is inside function widget

Answer (score 6):

If the script needs to go in the `<head>` section:

```
class Your_Widget extends WP_Widget{

  protected static $did_script = false;

  function __construct(){

    // parent::__construct() ...

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'scripts'));

  }

  function scripts(){

    if(!self::$did_script && is_active_widget(false, false, $this->id_base, true)){
      wp_enqueue_script('your-script');
      self::$did_script = true;
    }           

  }


}
```

Otherwise, Chip Bennett's solution will work for queuing it in the footer.

The `$did_script` static variable is not required, I used it just to avoid further unnecessary calls to `wp_enqueue_script` if there are multiple widget instances on the page...

Comment: Cool idea, but this doesn't actually address the OP's question, since `is-active_widget()` just lets you know whether a widget has been activated (ie: dragged into one of the sidebar areas in Appearance > Widgets), as opposed to actually appearing on any given page.

Comment: Condition is wrong: **(1)** `is_active_widget` will return a sidebar_id, even if that sidebar is not on displayed the current page. This will add the script on every page. **(2)** `wp_enqueue_script` will add a script only once, even if you call it multiple times. no need for `self::$did_script` **(3)** because `__construct` is called on every page request, even if the widget is not even displayed

Answer (score 2):

Pierre,

The way I handle this is with `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_dequeue_script`, and use a instance variable `$is_active` in the Your_Widget class

So do the `wp_enqueue_script` based on `is_active_widget` which enqueues the script on all pages but with the footer parameter set to true. Note the dequeue is run at a priority to make sure it runs before the scripts are output.

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
  if ( is_active_widget( false, $this->id, $this->id_base, true ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'your-script-handle', 'your-script-url', array(), '1.0', true );
    add_action( 'wp_footer', array($this,'dequeue_redundant_scripts'), 1 );
  }
```

}

Then in the widget function indicate if the widget is active on that page

```
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    // outputs the content of the widget
    $this->is_active = true;  
}
```

Then in the footer dequeue the script if the widget is not active on that page

```
function dequeue_redundant_scripts() {
    if (! $this->is_active) {
        wp_dequeue_script('your-script-handle');
    }
}
```

This approach of enqueue then dequeueing if unused also works well for plugins that define shortcodes which require scripts

Answer (score 0):

I considered 'wp_footer' hook because this hook is executed at footer,and is probably the best way to add scripts only where the widget is used.

```
class Your_Widget extends WP_Widget{

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {

         add_action('wp_footer',array($this,'front_end_scripts'));

    }

    function front_end_scripts(){
       ?><script type="text/javascript">
          console.log('this works!');
        /*
          Or if you need external scripts then you may use 
          $.getScript([your-script-url] );
        */
        </script> <?php
    }



}
```

Comment: Ugh. `wp_enqueue_script()` please. No direct printing of JS.

Comment: I'm afraid wp_enqueue_script() will not work here since the hook besides wp_enqueue_script is fired much before the widget is actually called.

Comment: You can call wp_enqueue_script() any time before the wp_footer action. The widget is called during the building of the template page. You can either hook onto `dynamic_sidebar` action, detecting when your widget is actually displayed, or, more simply, just put your `enqueue_script()` right into the `widget()` method, as @ChipBennet recommends.