# Looking for a Wordpress plugin to show five latest tweets one at a time?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation

As the question suggests, I'm looking for a plugin that can cycle through my latest five tweets one at a time, and via Javascript/jQuery, it automatically rotates between the tweets on a set interval.

I've looked at quite a few, and all of them can only either show one or multiple, but with no automatic cycling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice idea for a plugin!
I started to write one with Widget, Shortcode and Options page but will have to take on it later on...

Meanwhile, I've published the bare bone, that is: a plugin for doing a Tweet Cycler Widget.
https://github.com/brasofilo/tuit-cycler

The CSS adjustments and the Cycle plugin configuration have to be done directly in the code, check the FAQ.
Here's an excpert of the ReadMe:

> ## Tuit Cycler
>
> WordPress plugin for displaying a Widget with x numbers of Tweets from a specific user. Displays one tweet at a time, and rotates them using the jQuery Cycle Plugin.
>
> ### Description
>
> Based on this [WordPress Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/52074/12615), by Anriëtte Combrink.
>
> Uses [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) and [jQuery Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).
>
> Function for grabbing the Tweets grabbed from the plugin [Twitter Hash Tag Shortcode](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-hash-tag-shortcode/), by Bainternet.
>
> A little trick for registering the Javascript files only when Widget active from this [WordPress Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48385/12615), by One Trick Pony.
>
> A little touch of style in the Widget admin area from this [WordPress Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3003/12615), by Jan Fabry.
>
> ### Screenshot
>
> [image: Tuit Cycler]

Comment: Thank you very much, I already installed this, only problem is it doesn't fetch tweets from the specified Twitter user. Can you look into this?

Comment: @AnriëtteCombrink - Sooorry, I made a last minute var name change and bugged it... Updated the Git, should be all k now...

Answer (score 3):

while I can't offer a simple plugin solution right offhand it'd be really simple to build the functionality with twitter.js and jQuery cycle with minimal knowledge of js/jQuery.

Read up on how to implement twitter.js here:
http://remysharp.com/2007/05/18/add-twitter-to-your-blog-step-by-step/

cycle
https://github.com/malsup/cycle

basically just setup your twitter.js to call in 5 most latest, wrap them in a container LI's and set cycle to cycle those LI's.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the Cycle plugin, it was of good use :o)

Comment: My only problem is, I want to keep it updatable from a client POV. I can do the code fine, it's just it needs to be editable by client.

Answer (score 0):

try my plugin [**`Twitter Hash Tag Shortcode`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-hash-tag-shortcode/)
witch lets you display the most recent twitter status updates for a particular hash tag in your posts/pages using shortcode.

USAGE:

```
[hashtag_tweets hashtag="YOUR_TAG" number="5"]
```

Comment: I did a good use of your code too, Bainternet! Also found a glitch and posted it in the plugin forum.

Comment: This is not really what I want, seeing that it only does hashtags, and I need specific tweets from a specific Twitter user.

Comment: set your tag as you name